# Addition to faq or /ask: Stick around

Tags: discussion, help-center, help

I think this should be added to the faq and/or on the /ask page:

Advice to stick around for about 15 minutes after posting. Often this is the time when the fate of a question (or answer) is decided (at least on SO). Close votes are cast, obviously missing information is asked for and improvements are suggested. It's quite an annoyance to look at a 1 minute old question, spend 2 minutes reading it and finding out that a trivial detail is missing for me to be able to provide an answer, commenting about it and then receiving an answer in 2 days when I completely forgot what was the question about.

I think that newbies simply don't expect SO to react so quickly to their questions and don't refresh the page after a couple of minutes. It might be a good idea to suggest doing so.

Comment: +1 for the stick around proposal.

Comment: That stick around thing should really be for answers, too. Thanks to the Community flag as well as attentive users, we catch a lot of non-answers within minutes of their posts, and provide helpful comments. But the user doesn't even show up for hours, nevermind just after having posted it.

Comment: @Grace: Of course not.. they're too busy going off to cross-post to the rest of the web!