# Add a hint to stay put after posting a question

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, questions, responses

## The Problem

**It happens on every second question I try to answer: The question is unclear but the user does not respond.**

Why? The usual reason is that the user asking a question seems to leave. Probably to come back later and check if there is any answer.

But on Stack Overflow that doesn't always work so well since there are very often comments asking for clarification.

And if the clarification is not provided, the question gets closed, gets ignored and/or downvoted.

That is really a pity since the first few minutes is the time when a question gets the most attention - especially on Stack Overflow where we have thousands of questions every day and every few seconds a new one. People move on very quickly to the next.

## The Solution

#### Can we please add a hint telling the user to stay put for at least a few minutes?!

Maybe in **the question form**, or when **taking the tour**, or by an **online indicating icon** visible in the question or at least when **closing the browser tab** containing the question.

We could tell the user something like @ThinkingStiff suggested:

> Things happen quickly on Stack Overflow. Expect comments requesting clarification shortly. Editing your question to satisfy these comments can help get your question answered more accurately.

I think this would also really help in reducing the flood of questions being pushed  in the review queue every day.

Comment: `"Things happen quickly on Stack Overflow. Expect comments requesting clarification shortly. Editing your question to satisfy these comments can help get your question answered more accurately."`

Comment: @ThinkingStiff: Sadly, no one ever reads that.

Comment: I normally comment, to leave a "marker" unless the question is _really_ crap and then come back later to see if the OP has changed anything. If not then VTC etc but there's always a chance that they have actually acknowledged it. Anything to keep them around for the first 20 minutes would be good. Bytes are cheap so spreading a few around to rescue a couple of newbies is a good thing. (I agree if it's not clear from the comment!)

Comment: Possible duplicates [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26548/when-a-question-is-posted-can-we-advise-the-poster-to-hang-around-and-respond-t), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84425/addition-to-faq-or-ask-stick-around) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185844/first-minutes-on-a-new-users-post/185848#185848).

Comment: ...or, even more annoyingly, time is wasted answering based on wrong assumptions.

Comment: In low traffic tags you can wait weeks for answer, so that message would be simply not true and misleading. It could actually discourage new users by giving false promises.

Answer (score 42):

It's almost become a cliche on Meta that any message we display to new users will necessarily go unread.

I think a fairly clear, simple, and obvious message displayed to new users right after they ask their question could be quite helpful.

[image]

Comment: Similar to the "we don't want to put any effort into hand-holding these users because they are most likely hopeless" argument you see on here a lot (especially regarding post bans).  +1 because I think this could be effective, despite going against the common arguments around here.

Comment: @jadarnel27 - what you describe has long been another pet peeve of mine.

Comment: @jadarnel27 What exactly makes you think this can be more effective than the already existing ways (which get regularly ignored)?

Comment: @Alenanno - because the regular ways are embedded in FAQ pages that normal people don't read.  Ever.  I'm a 20K user and even **I** haven't read the faq.

Comment: @AdamRackis Not really: Did you read the message the first time you posted a question? This is one more thing that people won't read. I still don't see why *this* would be any different, honestly... I have read the FAQ. The problem is not the place, the problem is that some users simply don't bother reading it, no matter where you put it.

Comment: @Alenanno - I don't know - I don't remember even seeing the message. Is it displayed in the page where you type your message in, or is it displayed in the actual question that you see when you post your new question?  I think the above could be helpful because it's visible on the actual question after you post it.  Some people will ignore it, but I think plenty will read it.

Comment: @AdamRackis If I remember correctly, it's displayed right after you click on "Ask question" (a new page opens). When you accept this page, you'll be brought to the usual Writing-the-question page. I tried making a new account and asking a question to post a screenshot here, but it didn't work. :P

Comment: @Alenanno - ah.  That's what I mean.  Anything you put between the user and his asking of a question is likely to be ignored.  Users—especially developers, which we all are—will almost always ignore instructions like that.  But displaying it on the question itself, after the user has asked it, could I think me marginally useful.

Comment: @AdamRackis I'm not sure about that, but again, we can't all have the same opinion. :P

Comment: Can the message display be made more obnoxious and intrusive, perhaps?  That isn't sarcasm; it's a suggestion.

Comment: @Alenanno - please specify the "regularly ignored existing ways" which you declare in your first comment.

Comment: @JoshDM I have mentioned them while talking to Adam in this comment thread. If you check the other comments I wrote I mention all of them. :D Some of that has change since then, though.

Comment: Perhaps this could work as a JavaScript alert after they submit the question.

Answer (score 6):

## NO

Conversely, we get new users who expect Stack Overflow to behave like a chat room and start spamming comments on their question (ok, that doesn't bother anyone else), on other people's post (yes, some of them do that even after they reach 50 reputation), and via flags (yes, moderators waste time declining “y no answre for 10 minutes its urgent” flags).

We also have new users who accept the first answer they get and leave after 10 minutes, even if that answer was completely wrong.

Let's not encourage them.

It's perfectly fine to post a question and come back the next day. The important point is to provide the requested clarifications, not how fast they are provided.

A question can be closed in minutes, so telling askers to hang on won't even prevent that.

Answer (score 3):

Sadly, most users won't read that.

When a user registers, he "must" read the FAQ, he is provided with help messages every step of the way, encouraging him to add details and code. When their questions get closed, they don't bother reading why, they just open it again, hoping to get an answer, not realizing their question is bad.

Adding *yet another* warning sign won't solve the problem. Only put a further obstacle between the user and his question (Even though the question was already submitted).

No. Sadly, most users only respond to the sting of downvotes and closes/deletions. And if that's not enough, they're banned.

Comment: How **must** a user read the FAQ?

Comment: @juergend: You sign on it ("I have read and accepted") when you register IIRC. It was said once, but I haven't tried it. I said "must" because most users scroll through and press OK.

Comment: [Yes, I have read and accepted the Terms and Conditions](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Iip4H.jpg).

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: I don't think that "terms and conditions" include reading the complete FAQ. And since nobody reads that like you say a hint in the question form would be much better.

Comment: @juergend Were you talking to me? Mine was just a (serious) joke. Anyways, if I remember correctly, before posting a question you *are* asked to read the FAQ.

Comment: Nobody ever reads a site's faq before starting.  But a big message right in front of the user, displayed after asking a question?  There's a good chance the user will see / read that.

Comment: @AdamRackis: Find? yes. Read? Not likely.

Comment: FYI -- [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7441/can-and-should-more-be-done-to-encourage-users-to-search-first-and-ask-only-if/9710#9710) details one of the "required to click through" pages that new users get. (CC @Alenanno) edit: oops, link added =)

Comment: @jadarnel27 I think you forgot to link. :P

Comment: Imagine that someone somehow discovered a way to prevent you from accessing their website until you've actually read all the terms and conditions.   How many people would just walk away if that happened?

Comment: but just think of all the fun that you could have with those [T&C](https://xkcd.com/501/)

Comment: Well, I guess I'm the 1%. I read the T&C or ToS, or whatever they're called before doing stuff. I want to be sure of what I'm agreeing to. For all you know, PayPal's T&C could say they are allowed to commit fraud on behalf of you. There was one on TDWTF about a game that said in the liability part about how they aren't responsible if the game "kills your family".

Comment: @ColeJohnson too bad McDonalds' lawyer's didn't have a HotDrink FAQ... BTW, make that 1.001% - I read 'em too. :))

Comment: @Alenanno "I agree..." = biggest lie on the Internet.

Answer (score 3):

Your question suggests that a *hint* should only be offered to all question askers.

For users who have the [new-contributor-indicator](/questions/tagged/new-contributor-indicator) we should offer a tip to stay put for a few minutes, for **questions** ***and*** **answers**. The [goals of the New User Indicator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314287/282094) are clear, but they are defeated if someone posts and doesn't check back until hours or days later; often to their dismay if they've made a mistake.

I suggest that a tip to stick around and respond to comments or answers to questions should be limited to new users, and that such a hint should be offered on both questions and answers; but only when the NCI is shown. It is a fair and useful *other side of the coin*.