# First minutes on a new users post

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Is it possible to add / inform clearly new users that the first minutes after they post a question they get 60-90 percent of the brain power people have to offer?

Most often, people post and go away for 1, 2 hours...

Comment: Do you have any data to back this up?

Comment: @Damien: No, but most comment/answer interaction happens in the first minutes of a post as I experience it. Anyone knows if my impression is right?

Comment: Agree @Bart, more than 2 years ago. And similar is still happening often. That question has still no answer. I really think Stackoverflow gains if they know that. What to do?

Comment: Even if this were true on Stack Overflow, it would only be true for the more popular tags.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When I posted [my first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157186/django-importerror-no-module-named-politifact-omniture-1-0) on Stack Overflow, I was in the middle of a project that was a bit beyond my skill set. I began Googling for an answer to a particularly stick problem and found SO after two or three attempts. I decided that it was as good a place as any, so I posted the question.

However, I still needed an answer, and I knew that real people need more than a few seconds to provide good answers. So I left, continued Googling and eventually returned to SO a few hours later.

In that case, it took 58 minutes for the first (and only) response to be posted. If I had been told to stick around, I would have been frustrated when the recommended time expired without a response ("*the system must be broken*").

I think people generally understand how these things work. Sure, it would be nice if the OP was around to clarify an active question, but it is not always necessary. Additionally, the question pops back to the top of the queue when an edit is made, so all is not lost if the response is not immediate.

In order to avoid setting false expectations, I think we should avoid implementing notices  such as this one.

Comment: Good point. Better a good surprise than frustration on a slow answer. Just feel sorry to see people with real problems loosing the brain power because they go away.

Answer (score 4):

On some of the sites that I belong to, the first view, let alone an answer may not occur for hours.  Some questions require the answerer to go away for a little why to research and contemplate their answer.

Some questioners may sit there refreshing the page immediately after posting.

I don't think that there is a hard and fast 'rule' about people's behaviour on SE.

Comment: Of course that it creates frustration if people refresh-refresh and nothing happens. But a kind of 5 min rule/suggestion wouldn't hurt.

Comment: @Sergio Then the question begs - would all users necessarily read it? But, as you say, it can't hurt +1